# Expect to receive with particular argument at least once

Tags: rspec

I have a Logger class. I want to test that inside the function, the Logger will receive a `log` call with `foo` argument.

```
expect(Logger).to receive(:log).with("foo")
Bar.foo()
```

However during this some model callback will also call `Logger.log("euu")`, `Logger.log("arr")`, `Logger.log("hmm")` and many others. Rspec seems to fails because `log` was called with some other arguments first.

I am only concerned that `log("foo")` is called once. Is there a way to do this kind of testing?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The approach is to allow calls to `log`, do your stuff, and then check that `log` has been called with the expected arguments, like this:

```
allow(Logger).to receive(:log)
Bar.foo
expect(Logger).to have_received(:log).with("foo")
```

RSpec calls this pattern [Spies](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/spies)

Answer (score 11):

You can use [Receive Counts](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop-rspec/RuboCop/Cop/RSpec/ReceiveCounts):

```
expect(Logger).to receive(:log).with('foo').at_least(:once)
```

Comment: Relishapp no longer exists, use: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop-rspec/RuboCop/Cop/RSpec/ReceiveCounts

Comment: Thank you @Narfanator! I have updated my answer.